# How to get rid of the following multiple alternatives warnings in my ANTLR3 grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

```
[11:45:19] warning(200): mygrammar.g:14:57: Decision can match input such as "','" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[11:45:19] warning(200): C:\Users\Jarrod Roberson\mygrammar.g:14:57: Decision can match input such as "','" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

I want to be able to nest functions inside other functions.

```
myfunction(x) ->
  sqr(a) -> a * a,
  y -> sqr(x).
```

here is the line it is complaining about

```
function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement (',' statement)* ;
```

and here is what it is considering the alternative

```
statement : ATOM
          | expression
          | assignment
          | function
          ;
```

I am using `.` as my statement end rule

```
program : (statement'.')*;
```

Here is what the synatx diagram looks like in ANTLRWorks

[image: syntax diagram]
<sub>(source: [vertigrated.com](http://www.vertigrated.com/images/alternatives.png))</sub>

I really like things to compile/work without any warnings. How do I resolve this warning condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Jarrod Roberson wrote:***
>
> I really like things to compile/work without any warnings. How do I resolve this warning condition?

Your parser can parse the following input:

```
f(x)-> g(y)-> y*y, x=y
```

in two different parse trees:

[image]

and:

[image]

You can fix this by forcing the parser to look ahead and make sure there is `',' statement` ahead before actually matching these rules. You can do that by using a syntactic predicate (the `(...)=>` part) with said rule inside:

```
function
  :  ID '(' args ')' '->' statement ((',' statement)=> ',' statement)* 
  ;
```

However, you don't need the predicate if your `function` rule has some sort of an "end" token, which you haven't defined. From your earlier questions, and your example:

```
myfunction(x) ->
  sqr(a) -> a * a,
  y = sqr(x).
```

it seems you're using the `'.'` as the end of a `function`. If you add that to your `function` rule:

```
function
  :  ID '(' args ')' '->' statement (',' statement)* '.'
  ;
```

you don't need a predicate at all.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, feel free to post a new question regarding that (if you get stuck on it, that is...).

Comment: the `.` at the end of the function is part of my `program` rule. `program : (statement'.')*;` not part of the function rule, this way it is consistent.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, ah, I see. By looking at the tree images, I hope it's clear why ANTLR is complaining: a `function` must also have an obvious end. By using a predicate, I believe the tree from the first image will be created (and therefor, the tree from image 2 can never be created!).

Comment: I realized my example strawman was wrong it should have a `->` where the `=` is.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, the `->` and `=` are not the problem here. Not putting in extraneous characters make your grammar ambiguous. Do you understand that the parser can take two "roads" while parsing `"f(x)-> g(y)-> y*y, x=y"` (see the images)? This is because you have not explicitly defined _when_ a `function` ends. Because you didn't do so, the last statement `x=y` (or `x->y`, it doesn't matter) can go _under_ function `f`, but also function `g`. By adding a predicate, your just suppressing the warning  while you should address it properly (fix the grammar/language).

Comment: I understand it is ambigious, I can't figure out how to make ANTLR look ahead and say, "hey this matches the longer alternative, I will go down that path" or "nope only the shorter one matches"